# Add .Net Framework 2.0 in VS Setup Project

Tags: setup-project, .net-framework-version

I have setup project that requires .Net Framework 2.0 before installation. So, I want to make my project to install .Net first and then my project.

How can I add .Net installation file inside my Setup Project and force it to install first during the installation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35976/Add-Prerequisites-of-NET-Framework-in-Visual-Studi)

[here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1396927.aspx)

You can also download the setup file of the .net framework and use setup maker applications to instruct the user to install it first. Please do a little web search for similar questions before asking here. :-)

EDIT:

First create a setup file for your visual studio project without the .net framework setup file. Then use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php) to make another setup file and in here use the option Inno setup provides to make the user to run the .net framework setup file first. This will make a single .exe file named `setup.exe` in you documents folder. See if this works for you.

Since .net framework and your program use the same install shield for installing, you can't use both of them at the same time when the other one is still running, that's why you need a different setup wizard than install shield.

EDIT(Inno Setup):

You can search **Run** in the index section of the help window for farther information. The programs are executed in the order appearance in your code in Inno Setup. So your Inno Setup `Run` section code should be something like this:

```
Filename: "{app}\.netFrameWorkSetup.exe"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
Filename: "{app}\yourAppSetup.exe";
```

Actually it didn't get as much explaining as I expected!

Comment: link that you posted is not what I really want. That creates a dotnetfx folder inside the Setup Project. I want to have .Net Framework installation file inside the .msi file. Is that posssible? So users install my project by downloading only 1 file.

Comment: By adding the .net framework to the prerequisites (the first link) you will have a single `.msi` and another `.exe`.

Comment: I did the same thing from first link, that creates the dotnetfx folder which .msi file refers to. It's also shown in the screen shots on that site.

Comment: Edited the answer, give that a try.

Comment: Hi Vahid. I tried it, it's working, but one question. While creating setup Wizaard in Inno Setup, I couldn't find the option to show which file should be installed first. Can you help?